# How can I use the Displace Modifier in a way that allows me to raise an artwork at one spot and recess it on another?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, objects, subdivision-surface, displacement

I am really in a tough spot here.

In the image below I want to add 5 addons that a company offers; all on the same panel:

[image]

Area1: I need it to be raised, embossed and a bit shiny according to the artwork, I need bump.

Area2: I need this in gold foil and area 3 on silver foil.

Area4: I need it debossed and shiny, I need recession according to the artwork at that place.

Area5: I need SPOT UV over there which is the same thing as embossing an artwork but its just not raised as much as embossing, slightly less.

I am able to recreate all these techniques individually and I have so far done it very well. But when I do that on the same panel I get too much geometry because I have to subdivide the mesh many times.

When I apply a displace modifier which does the job perfectly. I have it on the whole plane and I dont have control over embossing or debossing two different areas; I can only deboss the plane as a whole or emboss it.

The artworks are complicated and have a lot of curves and places where its either recessed or raised according to the maps I've created. I have been looking for a solution for quite some time and I found two time consuming ones:

1) Modeling everything and then just placing it on the plane. The part I think I can't model is where embossing or debossing is. Which doesn't actually solve the problem.

2) Subdividing a plane several times until the viewport lags. Selecting the part where I want something debossed or embossed. Separately selecting it as an object and applying a displace mod, keeping it at the same location; once its debossed; ctrl+j after applying mod. Readjusting everything. Which is the only solution I have found.

I want to know if there is another solution especially if its through the displace mod. If the solution I have found is the only one then I will have to shift to another software.

Please help.

Comment: Without seeing the actual logo/artwork whatever it is, Displacement really sounds like the wrong approach here, very inefficient and produce low quality. Why not just model it cleanly? Anyway you could have different displacement modifiers with different parameters for each part.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wish to go with displace, and you're working with displacing from an image texture, it should really just be a matter of calibrating the colors of the image texture.

50% gray = no displacement

white = full emboss, displace upwards

black = full deboss, displace downwards

Intermediate shades emboss/deboss a correspondingly intermediate amount

Using GIMP or the like, you should be able to composite your individual displacement maps into a single image so that everything is being displaced in the direction you wish. You may need to invert colors of various parts of the image, or modify the brightness/contrast (e.g., or levels, or curves, whatever) to control the relative amount of displacement.

Comment: Thats by far the simplest answer I have received, thank you.